# Is there any way to know which stored procedures ran through my code?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

SQL Server 2008

We have many sprocs, and just don't know which ones are being called, is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Profiler, located under Start > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > Performance Tools